# Get about -> title and about -> images -> name from my local .json file

Tags: arrays, json, angular, ngfor

I want to show all images in my app.component.html file using *ngFor loop.

This is my app.component.html

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<div class="container mt-4">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let users of Users">
    <h2>{{users.name}}</h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is my data.json

```
{
    "about": {
    "title":"STORY ABOUT US",
    "subtitle":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
      incididunt ut labore et",
    "images":[
      {
        "name":"aa1.jpg",
        "id":1,
        "link":"http://google.com/",
        "icon":"fa fa-link"
      },
      {
        "name":"aa2.jpg",
        "id":2,
        "link":"http://google.com/",
        "icon":"fa fa-link"
      }
    ]
}
```

This is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import sampleData from '../assets/data.json';

@Component({ selector: 'app-root', templateUrl: './app.component.html', styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] }) 
export class AppComponent { Users: any = sampleData; }
```

Comment: What code is in your `app.component.ts` and what have you tried?

Comment: This is my app.component.ts file code

    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import sampleData from '../assets/data.json';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      Users: any = sampleData;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Given your JSON data the component template should look like the following:

```html
<h1>{{users.about.title}}</h1>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let image of users.about.images">
    {{image.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

You want to loop over the iterable in your JSON data which is the `images` property and that is what `*ngFor` allows.

See a working [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfmdn9) I made with the above description.

Note I used the property name `users` lowercase, instead of `Users` uppercase, as it is a more common convention, but still an opinion.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt and valuable response. now it works perfectly fine, and most important you have solved this problem as I want. once again thanks

Comment: @deepakpanwar glad I could help :) perhaps consider marking this answer as accepted if it solved your problem so others coming along later find it too

Answer (score 0):

you can access your object property using two ways

**1**

> object.propertyName

**2**

> object['propertyName']

so import your json file into your object and access its properties like that

```
  <li *ngFor="let users of Users">
     <h2>{{users.name}}</h2>
     <h2>{{users.title}}</h2>
     <h2>{{users.image.name}}</h2>
     <h2>{{users.image.id}}</h2>
 </li>
```